# how to use jsp and thymeleaf in the same spring mvc project

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am newbie to thymeleaf.I want to use both jsp and thymeleaf in my spring mvc project, Everything seems perfect with the configuration but it is throwing the 404 exception as the "request resource is not available". Please help.

[image: 404 exception!]

And My Configuration goes like this:

**Spring-Servlet-Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myorg.controller" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**Spring-thymeleaf-config**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>MyThymeLeafProject</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>ContectConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>tiles3</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-*-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.myorg.controller;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyController {



    @RequestMapping(value="/decideView",params="thymebtn",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String thymview(@RequestParam("name")String name,Model model){

        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "mythymeleaf";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/decideView",params="jspbtn",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getView(@RequestParam("name") String name,Model model){

        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "myjspview";             
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form action="decideView">

Name:<input type="text" name="name" method="get">

<input type="submit" value="get from Jsp" name="jspbtn">

<input type="submit" value="get from thyme" name="thymebtn">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Thanks for your response's sam and marioosh I have worked as per your suggestion but still it is not working with the thymeleaf. I agree with @sam that it is reaching the JSP view resolver but not Thymeleaf resolver.When I have only thymeresolver it is working fine but it is not that I want.So I what can I do inorder to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of typos

- Your Project structure says the jsp folder name is under `views/jsp` but in prefix you have mentioned just `view`. So Change to
- 404 says `/WEB-INF/view/jsp/mythymeleaf.jsp` is not available.Ofcourse *yes*.It's present under `/WEB-INF/views/thymeleaf/mythymeleaf.jsp`

  - It's reaching to JSP because it is using `InternalResourceViewResolver` not `ThymeleafViewResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that paths (prefixes) for two resolvers conflicts beacause one contains another (`/WEB-INF/view` contains `/WEB-INF/view/jsp`). Try to move Your *.jsp views to another directory for example `/WEB-INF/jsp`, change internalViewResolver like below and should work.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Views examples:

```
/WEB-INF/view/thymeleaf/mythymeleaf.html
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
/WEB-INF/jsp/myjspview.jsp
```

Request mapping that works now:

```
@RequestMapping("/th")
public String th() {
    return "thymeleaf/mythymeleaf";
}

@RequestMapping("/jsp")
public String jsp() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/jsp2")
public String jsp2() {
    return "myjspview";
}
```

**Another configuration that looks better and works below**. I've changed prefix for internalViewResolver to `/WEB-INF/view/`. See that prefixes for reseolver are the same, but `ThymeleafViewResolver` have `viewNames` defined as `thymeleaf/*` so everything below `/WEB-INF/view/thymeleaf/` will be resolved by Thymeleaf.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Not changed:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Views:

```
/WEB-INF/view/thymeleaf/mythymeleaf.html
/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp
/WEB-INF/view/myjspview.jsp
```